# Incorrect output of user's input

Tags: c

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
  
  int hour, min;
  
  printf("Please insert the time in the 24 hour format (hh:mm): "); //ask user about the the time
  scanf("%d:%d", &hour, &min); //Store the time
  
  printf("%d", hour);//Checking to see what time I get
  
  if (hour == 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 23, 24){ //Check if the hour time matches
    printf("The closest departure time is 8:00 am and arriving at 10:16 am");
    return 0;
  }
  
  else if(hour = 8){//Check if the hour time matches
    printf("The closest departure time is 9:00 am and arriving at 10:16 am");
    return 0;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

When I input 08:00, it will always end up saying,"The closest departure time is 8:00 am and arriving at 10:16 am" when I want it to say "The closest departure time is 9:00 am and arriving at 10:16 am"

I looked back into my code to see if my first if statement contained 8:00 as an answer, but I don't see it there.

Comment: Neither `hour == 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 23, 24` nor `hour = 8` mean what you think they mean.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? Can you elaborate on what you are trying to say?

Comment: `hour = 8` assigns the value 8 to the variable hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines:

```
if (hour == 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 23, 24) ...
if (hour = 8) ...
```

will *not* do what you think they do. In the second one, that's an assignment rather than a check, so it's functionally equivalent to:

```
hour = 8; if (hour) ...
```

The first one is a bit trickier to unserstand but it involves the use of the comma operator. The expression `a, b` means: evaluate `a` and throw it away, then "return" `b`.

So your first line is basically the final condition from the list of conditions `{(hour == 1), (2), (3), ..., (24)}` or simply:

```
if (24) ...  // always true
```

Instead, you need:

```
if ((hour == 1) || (hour == 2) || ... || (hour == 24)) ...
if (hour == 8) ...
```

However, keep in mind that, if you need to check against a lot of disparate values, a `switch` statement can often be preferable:

```
switch (hour) {
    case  1: case  2: case  3: case  4: case  5:
    case  6: case  7: case 22: case 23: case 24: {
        printf ("Closest departure time is 8:00am, arriving at 10:16am");
        return 0;
    }
    case 8: {
        printf ("Closest departure time is 9:00am, arriving at 10:16am");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

For a few *ranges,* re-arranging the code can make it even shorter (sans comments):

```
// start as hour in inclusive range INT_MIN..INT_MAX

if (hour == 8) {
    printf ("Closest departure time is 9:00am, arriving at 10:16am");
    return 0;
}

// now INT_MIN..7 or 9..INT_MAX

if ((hour < 1) || (hour > 24) || ((hour > 7) && (hour < 22))) return 0;

// now 1..7 or 22..24

printf ("Closest departure time is 8:00am, arriving at 10:16am");
return 0;
```

---

Also keep in mind that the "normal" (in terms of the computer world, bizarre military standards notwithstanding) 24-hour clock goes from 00:00 to 23:59 so you may want to re-examine the values you're checking against.

Comment: main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:12:173: error: expected expression before ')' token
   if ((hour == 0) || (hour == 1) || (hour == 2) || (hour == 3) || (hour == 4) || (hour == 5) || (hour == 6) || (hour == 7) || (hour == 22) || (hour == 23) ||(hour == 24) ||){
                                                                                                                                                                             ^

exit status 1

Comment: @narusin, that's simply the `||` following the `(hour==24)` - you only need that if there's another condition you want to `or` with. Get rid of it and it should compile okay.

Comment: I noticed that mistake, but is there any way to shorten that code?

Comment: @narusin Put the numbers in a Set and check for membership or check if hour is greater than 0 but less that 8, OR hour is greater than 21, but less than 25.

Comment: @narusin, there's plenty of ways to clean up the code, I've provided a couple in the update.